# Error ListenerRule with identifier Priority 10 is currently in use on listener with 9 rules currently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

I have the following (minimal test) cloudformation template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Test template

Resources:
  TestTargetGroupListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - Type: fixed-response
          FixedResponseConfig:
            ContentType: text/plain
            MessageBody: It works
            StatusCode: 200
      Conditions:
        - Field: host-header
          HostHeaderConfig:
            Values:
              - example.com
      ListenerArn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:<accountid>:listener/app/<alb name>/xxx/xxx
      Priority: 10
```

When I attempt to deploy this I get the message:

> Resource of type 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule' with identifier 'Priority '10' is currently in use (Service: ElasticLoadBalancingV2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ..., Extended Request ID: null)' already exists." (RequestToken: ..., HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)

I have checked the listener and have confirmed that there are currently 9 rules (+ the last rule).

I have also tried setting priority to 9 (in case it is 0 based) and to 11 (because I wasn't sure if "last" counted in the priorities) however I get the same message (for each priority I tried).

This is how the listener rules look like:

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening. I used similar templates before without any issues on the same listener.

**Update:** I got this to work by using Listener priority 4 which (suprisingly) worked and made the listener appear in the console as 2nd! I still don't understand how it works. I figured out I could use 4 when I attempted to create an ECS service on the AWS web console, attached to the same load listener and had the same issue when selecting listener priority. However on the web console I was able to try numbers a lot quicker than via a CF template. I still do not understand what the issue was here and I still do not know how to properly diagnose this error.

**Update 2**

The new AWS console now shows the rule priority in addition to the ordinal (which was the only thing shown before) so this is no longer an issue.

Comment: What you don't show us in the screen shot are the actual priorities. Those are *not* in the first column.
If you honor [A listener can't have multiple rules with the same priority](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule-priority) you should be fine.
Yes this is a pain. For `ListenerRule`, AWS  CloudFormation utterly violates  its _desired state configuration_ contract.

Comment: It's not just a pain. From what I can figure out it's practically impossible to use CloudFormation/CDK to apply ListenerRules due to the inability to find existing rules or in any other way determine an available priority. You can use a random number and risk collisions - that's basically all you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon the same issue. You can find the priorities by first going to EC2 management console, there select your Load balancer, open Listeners-tab and click desired listener id, it opens to a new tab. And the priorities are shown on the Rules-tab.

Comment: But in automations, this value needs to be known before the deploy

Comment: Yes, yes it does and it's a major failing of CloudFormation/CDK that it provides no way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of unbelievable that AWS Cloudformation hasn't solved this yet.

I needed to add new rules and re-arrange all priorities in live environments.
After modifying my template with the new listeners and the priorities update, I deployed it, and it failed due to the "existing priority" error.

For the ones in a hurry, the only thing that worked for me in this scenario was to make a copy of my template and delete all listeners, deploy those changes, and then take my original template with the new and updated listener rules and deploy it again so that no conflicts could arise. "Inspired" by [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/failing-stack-updates-deleted/).

Things you should not do since they will fail:

- manually delete all rules and try to re-create them from the CloudFormation template.
- re-create the rules manually as they are in the CFT, and then try to update the stack.
- Using higher/different priorities temporarily to update in 2 steps works sometimes, and sometimes it creates conflicts.